# Python output to a .json format

Tags: python, json, type-conversion

This is a part of a program that extracts TLS Client Hello information from captured packets in "real-time".

```
def parse_client_hello(handshake):
    if isinstance(handshake.data, dpkt.ssl.TLSClientHello):
        client = dpkt.ssl.TLSClientHello(str(handshake.data))
        print(' (***) The version of the TLS supported by the client: {0}'
            .format(tls_dictionary('tls_version',client.version)))
        session_id, pointer = parse(client.data, 1)
        print(' (***) The session ID of the client: {0} '
            .format(hexlify(session_id)))
        ciphersuites, pointer1 = parse(client.data[pointer:], 2)
        ciphersuites, pretty_cipher_suites = parse_extension(ciphersuites, 'cipher_suites')
        print(' (***) The cipher suites proposed by the client: {0} '
            .format(pretty_cipher_suites))
        print(' (***) The random of the client: {0} '.format(client.random))
        pointer += pointer1 
        compression_methods, pointer1 = parse(client.data[pointer:], 1)
        compression_methods, pretty_compressions = parse_extension(compression_methods,
            'compression_methods')
        print(' (***) The compression methods: {0} '.format(pretty_compressions))
        sys.stdout.flush()
```

The output of this part displayed on the terminal is:

```
    (***) The version of the TLS supported by the client: TLS 1.2
    (***) The session ID of the client: f72434d3e6d82d0798a78192516ba69623603a6d358a6f17642fc34dc67bab72 
    (***) The cipher suites proposed by the client: ['TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256', 'TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256', 'TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256', 'TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256', 'TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384', 'TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384', 'TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA', 'TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA', 'TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA', 'TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA', 'TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256', 'TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384', 'TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA', 'TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA', 'TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA'] 
    (***) The random of the client: �.�׏45���M�܌    s=�����GIA��k~�� 
    (***) The compression methods: ['null']
```

My goal is to prettyfy the output data and to convert it into a .json format and the output should be printed in a file.

What I want to obtain is something like this:

```
Version: TLS 1.2
Session ID: f72434d3e6d82d0798a78192516ba69623603a6d358a6f17642fc34dc67bab72
Cipher Suites: ['TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256',            'TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256','TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256', 'TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256','TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384', 'TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384','TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA', 'TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA','TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA', 'TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA','TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256', 'TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384', 'TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA', 'TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA', 'TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA']
Random: �.�׏45���M�܌    s=�����GIA��k~�� 
Compression Method: null
```

Do you have any idea of where should I start or any suggestion?

Comment: Please repeat [how to ask]( https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask),  from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  Asking us to teach you how to design a custom program is off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Do you realize that the expected format is not a json format?

Answer (score 0):

Put all the data you want into a dictionary:

```
obj = {}
obj["Version"] = ...
obj["Session ID"] = ...
...
```

or inline

```
obj = {"Version": ..., "Session ID": ..., ...}
```

and use the json library to dump that into a file:

```
import json
with open(filename, "w") as f:
    json.dump(obj, f)
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure.

Create a dict like this:

```
response = {
   'Version': tls_dictionary('tls_version',client.version)
   'Session ID': hexlify(session_id)
   'Cipher Suites': pretty_cipher_suites
   'Random': client.random
   'Compression Method': pretty_compressions
}
```

Then `json_response = json.dumps(response)`.